# Why it is common to use anchor inside list item for navbar?

Tags: html

I could not find any information, why it is common to use anchor in list item in navbar?

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="/one">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="/two">Two</a></li>
</ul>
```

Even [navbar in Bootstrap 3](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) is implemented in such way

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Even now some HTML-coders use it and teach to do it.
Why should I use this awkward markup? Then I have to "clean" all browser-default styles for list-items `list-style-type: none;` and put inside each list item an anchor for navigation link?

What is wrong with this, below?

```
<div class="nav">
  <span><a href="/one">One</a></span>
  <span><a href="/two">Two</a></span>
</div>
```

`<span>` or `<div>` does not matter.
It is already 3 years of HTML5, what is wrong with this, below?

```
<nav>
  <a href="/one">One</a>
  <a href="/two">Two</a>
</nav>
```

Is it connected some-how with old browsers? If yes, give me a link to read what was wrong, please.

Comment: Read this (and its follow-ups): https://css-tricks.com/navigation-in-lists-to-be-or-not-to-be/

Comment: Because semantically a list makes more sense than divs and spans

Answer (score 1):

Because the `li`s (= "list items") *list*  the available pages of that website. That's a semantic concept in HTML, its inherent logic works well mainly for accessibility on websites and for search engines (again: *listing*  the pages of that website).

Answer (score 1):

`<div>` and `<span>` is valid but not semantic since a navbar is essentially a list.

I usually use this approach:

```
<nav>
 <ul>
  <li class="navbar-item"><a href=#>placeholder</li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

This is both semantic and can be cleanly styled using css child selectors.